# SQL query to insert default values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write a SQL query that would INSERT INTO `CarSettings` (fuelType='gasoline', doorCount=4) WHERE `Cars.id` does not exist as foreign key in `CarSettings.carId`.

Right now I have those default field values (fuelType='gasoline', doorCount=4) hardcoded in the codebase and if there is no entry for that `carId` in `CarSettings` table I use those hardcoded values. But this was obviously not a good idea, so now I need a query that would set those default settings values to all cars and insert them to `CarSettings` table.

Tables and structure:

Table **Cars**

```
id, name, description
```

Table **CarSettings** (one-to-one)

```
id, carId (FK Cars.id), fuelType, doorCount
```

Comment: Sample data and desird results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INSERT` with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO CarSettings (carid, fuelType, doorCount)
    SELECT c.id, 'gasoline', 4
    FROM cars c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CarSetting cs WHERE c.id = cs.carId);
```

Comment: Hey, you solution works perfectly, thank you. I apologize for not including sample data and desired results, but it would seem you were able to decipher the desired result. Again thank you very much! Cheers!